# How to set all data in a slice, got from mongodb using mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB that has dynamic keys and set it in a slice.

Here is my data sample:

```
_id ObjectIdHex("5911786dc28f25578150501d")
2017-05-01 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("59117897c28f25578150501e")
2017-05-02 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("5911789ec28f25578150501f")
2017-05-03 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
2017-05-04 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("591178a6c28f255781505020")
_id ObjectIdHex("591178abc28f255781505021")
2017-05-05 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("591178b0c28f255781505022")
2017-05-06 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("591178b5c28f255781505023")
2017-05-07 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("591178bac28f255781505024")
2017-05-08 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
_id ObjectIdHex("591178c8c28f255781505025")
2017-05-09 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
2017-05-10 [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]
```

I need to set it into an array like `{2017-05-09 : [800 1000 1200 1400 1600]}` and same for other entries.

I have tried

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    //"encoding/json"
)

type Spot struct{
    Id      bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Spots   map[string]interface{} `json:"spots"`
}

//type Values []Value

//var result []struct{ Value int }
type Spots []Spot

func getAllSpots() (Spots) {
    mongoSession := getDbSession()

    sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()
    var spots []Spot
    c := mongoSession.DB("test").C("spots")
    var data []bson.M
    err := c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        // TODO: Do something about the error
    }

    test := make(map[string]int)
    for _, doc := range data {
      for key, value := range doc {
        if(key == "_id"){
            test[key] = value
            fmt.Println(key, value)
        }
      }
    }    

    return spots
}
```

I am able to get the spots in data and able to write the output to the console using `fmt.Println()` but when I assign it to a slice it gives me the following error:

> cannot use value (type interface {}) as type int in assignment: need type assertion

I searched all over the web but couldn't find a valid solution. Can anyone please guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is that error reported on?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M), you'll see that it's just an alias for `map[string]interface{}`. That means when you `range` over it, your key is a `string`, and your value is an `interface{}`. Your target is a `map[string]int`. So when you `test[key] = value`, you're trying to assign `value` (an `interface{}`) to something expecting an `int`, which you can't do without an explicit cast (aka [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15)). This is exactly what the error message says: `cannot use value (type interface {}) as type int in assignment: need type assertion`. You could instead do:

```
test[key] = value.(int)
```

But as a putu noted, it looks like those values are actually arrays of `int`s, which doesn't fit the `test` type at all, as it is a map of strings to single `int` values. So you'd need to either change the type of `test` to `map[string][]int` or pick a value from the source array to store in the map, e.g.

```
test[key] = (value.([]int))[0]
```

Comment: Since the data is an array of number, I think it should be `value.([]int)` or maybe `value.([]float64)`. Isn't it?

Comment: Hi @Adrian Thanks guys for the response. I would check it soon but because I got engaged in some other high priority work, so not able to check it right now. Thanks!